# Query on a SQL Server view with openquery to Hive returning wrong answer

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, oledb, linked-server

I have a view in SQL Server which is running an `OPENQUERY` to Hive through `MS OLE DB` Provider. The view is getting all the records from the Hive table without any `WHERE` clause.

Now, I suspect that a query on the SQL Server view to find `MAX` value on a column is sometimes returning wrong value. In any case, is it possible that the `MAX` query ran on the view even in case it wasn't able to fetch all the records from the Hive table, due to which the query returned wrong values?

View script:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[session]  
AS 
   SELECT distinct 
       a, b, c, d
   FROM 
       OPENQUERY(Hive, 'select distinct a, b, c, d from HiveDB.HiveTable')
```

Query on view:

```
SELECT TOP 1 a 
FROM [dbo].[session] 
ORDER BY a DESC
```

`a` is date in the format `yyyyMMddhh`, the data type is `int`.